# Create filters with multiple callbacks on plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have recently started to work with plotly in order to create interactive dashboards. I am still learning about it, so I would like to know the best practices in order to create filters which affects several figures in my app.

This is what my `app.py` looks like:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import Timestamp

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

data = {'Id Incidencia': {0: 'INC000006722157',
  1: 'INC000006722000',
  2: 'INC000006721939',
  3: 'INC000006708347',
  4: 'INC000006723090',
  5: 'INC000006736601',
  6: 'INC000006736721',
  7: 'INC000006724926',
  8: 'INC000006725331',
  9: 'INC000006725229',
  10: 'INC000006722542',
  11: 'INC000006722729',
  12: 'INC000006723246',
  13: 'INC000006722574',
  14: 'INC000006741563',
  15: 'INC000006722571',
  16: 'INC000006741632',
  17: 'INC000006741568',
  18: 'INC000006741636',
  19: 'INC000006741640'},
 'Fecha Apertura': {0: Timestamp('2020-12-07 12:28:30'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-12-07 09:52:06'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-12-07 10:13:06'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-12-02 09:02:45'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-12-07 20:37:53'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-12-12 00:35:16'),
  6: Timestamp('2020-12-12 00:46:48'),
  7: Timestamp('2020-12-08 15:21:15'),
  8: Timestamp('2020-12-08 20:04:14'),
  9: Timestamp('2020-12-08 18:33:54'),
  10: Timestamp('2020-12-07 15:52:59'),
  11: Timestamp('2020-12-07 18:33:22'),
  12: Timestamp('2020-12-07 23:56:08'),
  13: Timestamp('2020-12-07 17:11:05'),
  14: Timestamp('2020-12-14 13:31:05'),
  15: Timestamp('2020-12-07 17:06:55'),
  16: Timestamp('2020-12-14 13:44:35'),
  17: Timestamp('2020-12-14 13:33:40'),
  18: Timestamp('2020-12-14 13:46:38'),
  19: Timestamp('2020-12-14 13:51:34')}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Fecha Apertura"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Fecha Apertura"])
df = df.set_index('Fecha Apertura')

periods = [('D', '%Y-%m-%d'), ('M', '%Y-%m'), ('Y', '%Y')]
grouped_data = df.groupby(df.index.to_period(periods[0][0]))["Id Incidencia"].count()
fig2 = px.line(
    x=grouped_data.index.strftime(periods[0][1]),
    y=grouped_data.values,
    title='Distribución temporal de las incidencias',
    labels={
        'x': 'Fecha',
        'y': 'Nº incidencias'
    }
)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='groupby-period',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Día', 'value': 0},
            {'label': 'Mes', 'value': 1},
            {'label': 'Año', 'value': 2}
        ],
        value=0,
        clearable=False,
        searchable=False
    ),

    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='date-picker-range',
        start_date_placeholder_text="Fecha Inicio",
        end_date_placeholder_text="Fecha Fin",
        calendar_orientation='horizontal',
    ),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='line-chart-apertura',
        figure=fig2
    )
])

@app.callback(
    Output('line-chart-apertura', 'figure'),
    Input('groupby-period', 'value')
)
def update_graphs_by_period(period):
    periods = [('D', '%Y-%m-%d'), ('M', '%Y-%m'), ('Y', '%Y')]
    grouped_data = df.groupby(df.index.to_period(periods[period][0]))["Id Incidencia"].count()

    fig = px.line(
        x=grouped_data.index.strftime(periods[period][1]),
        y=grouped_data.values,
        title='Distribución temporal de las incidencias',
        labels={
            'x': 'Fecha',
            'y': 'Nº incidencias'
        }
    )

    fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)

    return fig

@app.callback(
    Output('line-chart-apertura', 'figure'),
    [
        Input('date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
        Input('date-picker-range', 'end_date')
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def filter_by_date_range(start_date, end_date):
    if start_date is None or end_date is None:
        return dash.no_update

    start_date_object = datetime.fromisoformat(start_date)
    end_date_object = datetime.fromisoformat(end_date)

    mask = (df.index >= start_date_object) & (df.index <= end_date_object)
    df_range = df.loc[mask]

    periods = [('D', '%Y-%m-%d'), ('M', '%Y-%m'), ('Y', '%Y')]
    grouped_data = df_range.groupby(df_range.index.to_period(periods[0][0]))["Id Incidencia"].count()
    fig = px.line(
        x=grouped_data.index.strftime(periods[0][1]),
        y=grouped_data.values,
        title='Distribución temporal de las incidencias',
        labels={
            'x': 'Fecha',
            'y': 'Nº incidencias'
        }
    )

    fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I will explain it a little:

- I have uploaded a simple `df` example with only the columns I am using on my example: a date column and an unique identifier one. When deployed, data will be retrieved from a cloud environment, so it is important to keep the original data.
- There are two filters which control the same line-chart figure (the idea is to apply them later to more different figures):

  - **Dropdown**: which defines the granularity of the line chart. It simply groups the timestamps by day, month or year depending on the user dropdown selection.
  - **Date picker range**: where the user can select a date range to be shown on the figure. It must be compatible with the other filter: if we select a date range, it must be shown according to the date granularity selected on the dropdown.

Until now, I have achieved to have both filters working independently, but I am struggling to have both of them working at the same time. I know my actual approach is not possible since a figure can only be affected by a single callback, so I need to combine them into a single one. However, I do not know what the cleanest and best practice method would be.

1. What is the cleanest way to merge both callback methods in one?
2. Is my approach of filtering by date range with `df_range = df.loc[mask]` the way I should do it, or would it be better to have a global df object like `df_to_show = df.copy()` and work with it instead?
3. Regarding to #2: how could I achieve that if a callback function modifies the `df_to_show` global variable, all the figures using it notice it so that they redraw themselves?

Comment: I had the similar thing when using multiple filters. they are all were dependent on each other. so I used `State` and if else condition.

Comment: @Pygirl Could you give me a little more information about your solution please?

Comment: So basically in my case I had three filters : date range, range slider(integer), drop-down(category). I wanted to make it dynamic let say if one of the column is getting selected by any of these filter then the other filter can't have those column in the list.

Comment: I solved this issue using state variable. And added if else condition. Say I have added column date as date range filter and filter the rows in between those dates. If I now use numerical slider range to get the filter on those above filtered rows. I will have to pass what's  df (filtered by date)  right now using state. I know it will be difficult for you to understand what I am saying.

Comment: I will be sharing you some link which will help you: https://community.plotly.com/t/updating-a-dropdown-menus-contents-dynamically/4920/2. https://community.plotly.com/t/dynamic-controls-and-dynamic-output-components/5519 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107660/properly-setting-up-callbacks-for-dynamic-dropdowns-plotly-dash

Comment: You can get some idea from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62715201/unable-to-append-in-the-div-children-component

Comment: I'm not sure how your app can run, because you have the same output in two callbacks. That's normally a fatal error for Dash. Check out using [multiple outputs in a single callback](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks), because that might be what you need.